# Upload local folder to Azure Blob Storage using BlobServiceClient with Python V12 SDK

Tags: python, azure, upload, azure-blob-storage

**Summarize the problem:**

I am trying to upload a local folder to Blob Storage using BlobServiceClient with Python. Some of the questions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58394403/how-to-recursively-upload-folder-to-azure-blob-storage-with-python/58405536?noredirect=1#comment112116425_58405536) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53227677/upload-multiple-files-from-folder-to-azure-blob-storage-using-azure-storage-sdk) do not work because `create_blob_from_path()` doesn't work in V12 SDK and I wouldn't want to go back to older version.

**What I've tried:**

I am using `os.walk` for local directory but missing the most important part like a function similar to `create_blob_from_path()`.

**Sample code:**

```
from azure.storage.blob import BlobServiceClient, BlobClient, ContainerClient, PublicAccess
import os 

base_file_path = '/path/to/my/local/directory/'
connect_str = '1q2w3e4r5t6y'
container_name = 'abc'

try: 
    blob_service_client = BlobServiceClient.from_connection_string(connect_str)
    container_name = 'abc' # already created in Azure 
    container_client = blob_service_client.get_container_client(container_name)
   
    upload_local_file_path = base_file_path + 'csv-summary-output' # input folder path

    for root, subdir, local_file in os.walk(upload_local_file_path):
        if local_file:
            for name in local_file:
                dir_part = os.path.relpath(root, upload_local_file_path)
                file_path = os.path.join(root, name)
                ==> missing parts here
except Exception as ex:
    print('Exception:')
    print(ex)
```

Any help is much appreciated and I will take a look at Azure Github to see if anything useful there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can also use the code below(Assume the local folder is in `D:\aaa`, please feel free to modify the code as per your need):

```
from azure.storage.blob import BlobServiceClient, BlobClient, ContainerClient,PublicAccess
import os

def run_sample():    
    conn_str="xxx"
    container_name="xxx"    
    
    path_remove = "D:\\"
    local_path = "D:\\aaa" #the local folder

    service_client=BlobServiceClient.from_connection_string(conn_str)
    container_client = service_client.get_container_client(container_name)  

    for r,d,f in os.walk(local_path):
        if f:
            for file in f:
                file_path_on_azure = os.path.join(r,file).replace(path_remove,"")
                file_path_on_local = os.path.join(r,file)

                blob_client = container_client.get_blob_client(file_path_on_azure)

                with open(file_path_on_local,'rb') as data:
                    blob_client.upload_blob(data)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    run_sample()
    print("**completed**")
```

Comment: Thanks for your response and time. Let me test it out first and read docs about `get_blob_client`.

Answer (score 0):

OK. With the help of [source code from Git](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-python/blob/58cdc8acfe9c8720096d77dbb2c758ef22ce6aff/sdk/storage/azure-storage-blob/samples/blob_samples_directory_interface.py#L45), I was able to figure out the solution and I am posting here for future references. I was *very* confused about `dest` variable and was even looking for *container's url* to give an upload path. It's actually been taken care of in `upload_dir` function. Any other suggestions are also welcomed.

**Sample code:**

```
from azure.storage.blob import BlobServiceClient, BlobClient, ContainerClient, PublicAccess
import os 

base_file_path = '/path/to/your/local/directory/'
# target_folder is the subfolder under container_name 
target_folder = 'xyz' 
 
connect_str = '1q2w3e4r5t6y7u8i9o0p'
container_name = 'abc'

def upload_file(source, dest):
    
    print(f'Uploading {source} to {dest}')
    with open(source, 'rb') as data:
      client.upload_blob(name=dest, data=data)

def upload_dir(source, dest):

    prefix = '' if dest == '' else dest + '/'
    prefix += os.path.basename(source) + '/'
    for root, dirs, files in os.walk(source):
        for name in files:
            dir_part = os.path.relpath(root, source)
            dir_part = '' if dir_part == '.' else dir_part + '/'
            file_path = os.path.join(root, name)
            blob_path = prefix + dir_part + name
            upload_file(file_path, blob_path)
try:
    source = base_file_path + target_folder
    dest = '' # dest is the target folder name  
    service_client = BlobServiceClient.from_connection_string(connect_str)
    client = service_client.get_container_client(container_name)
except Exception as ex:
    print('Exception:')
    print(ex)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    upload_dir(source=source, dest=dest)
```